# How to import erlang files from other erlang files

Tags: erlang

How to import erlang files from another erlang files.
I would like to import whole script not only specific modules.
Example:
How can we import below file in another erlang script??

```
% hello world program
-module(helloworld). 
-export([start/0]). 

start() -> 
   io:fwrite("Hello, world!\n").
```

Comment: Here is a guide how to format code in questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

Simply import it using the `-import` directive. Here's an example importing your `helloworld` module:

```erlang
-module(top).
-import(helloworld, [start/0]).
-export([myfun/0]).

myfun() ->
    start().
```

If you save the above in `top.erl`, you can then use it in the shell like this:

```
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.7.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:6:6] [ds:6:6:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [dtrace]

Eshell V10.7.1  (abort with ^G)
1> c(top).
{ok,top}
2> top:myfun().
Hello, world!
ok
```

Comment: Thank you so much..Getting below error while running this command "erl -noshell -s top start -s init stop"
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{top,start,[],[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ({undef,[{top,start,[],[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]})

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done

Comment: I'm able to run it from shell as you have mentioned above but not able to run by using this command (. i.e "erl -noshell -s top start -s init stop") even after creating ".beam" files.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm able to run it from shell as you have mentioned above but not able
> to run by using this command:
>
> ```
> erl -noshell -s top start -s init stop
> ```
>
> even after creating ".beam" files.

1. 

```
~/erlang_programs$ ls a.*
a.erl

~/erlang_programs$ cat a.erl
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

go() ->
   io:fwrite("hello\n").
```

2. 

```
~/erlang_programs$ erlc a.erl
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported

~/erlang_programs$ ls a.*
a.beam  a.erl    

~/erlang_programs$ erl -noshell -s a go -s init stop
hello
```

Now, if your module is actually in a different directory than the directory where you are issuing the erl command, then you can use a flag to specify the path to the `.beam` file:

```
~/erlang_programs$ cd ..
~$ 

~$ erl -noshell -s a go -s init stop -pa ./erlang_programs
hello
```

Note that the module you posted is named `helloworld` and the function in that module is named `start`, yet your erl command is:

```
 erl -noshell -s top start -s init stop
```

That erl command requires a module named `top` to be present in the current directory.

Comment: Please find below my examples.
helloworld.erl:
-module(helloworld).
-export([start/0]).

start() ->
   io:fwrite("hello world\n").

and 
top.erl:
-module(top).
-import(helloworld, [start/0]).
-export([myfunc/0]).

myfunc() ->
   start().

I have created .beam files for both the files and trying to run below command.
erl -noshell -s top start -s init stop

Comment: Thank you so much..Now it is working fine. I have missed module name in the command and right command is  "erl -noshell -s top myfunc -s init stop".